# MySQL returns: errno: 150 - foreign key error

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

Here is my schema to create three tables. The third one has foreign keys from the following two. I do not know why MySQL cannot create the third one. The types for the columns match.

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `SET`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `SET` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `SET_ID` int(11) DEFAULT 0,
  `SET_NAME` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `SET_RELEASE_DATE` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `TYPE`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `TYPE` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `TYPE_ID` int(11) DEFAULT 0,
  `TYPE_NAME` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `CARD`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `CARD` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `CARD_ID` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `CARD_NAME` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SET_ID` int(11) DEFAULT 0,
  `TYPE_1` int(11) DEFAULT 0,
  `TYPE_2` int(11) DEFAULT 0,
  `TYPE_3` int(11) DEFAULT 0,
  `TYPE_4` int(11) DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `card_idfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`SET_ID`)
    REFERENCES `SET`(`SET_ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `card_t1fk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`TYPE_1`)
    REFERENCES `TYPE`(`TYPE_ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `card_t2fk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`TYPE_2`)
    REFERENCES `TYPE`(`TYPE_ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `card_t3fk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`TYPE_3`)
    REFERENCES `TYPE`(`TYPE_ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `card_t4fk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`TYPE_4`)
    REFERENCES `TYPE`(`TYPE_ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a foreign key relationship, the keys in question have to have an index on the referenced table (see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html)).

For instance, this code:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `SET`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `SET` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `SET_ID` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `SET_NAME` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `SET_RELEASE_DATE` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  index(set_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Fixes the problem on the `card_idfk_1` constraint.  Note:  you can use either `key` or `index` as the keyword.

Comment: Thanks, I don't remember this from my class. I thought that the types had to match.